# Find the sum of the series $1+(\frac 12 +\frac 13)\frac 14 +(\frac 14 +\frac 15)\frac{1}{4^2}.....$ upto $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$S = \frac 12 .\frac 14 + \frac 14.\frac{1}{4^2} + \frac 16 . \frac{1}{4^3} ....... + \frac 13. \frac 14 + \frac 15 . \frac{1}{4^2}.....$$

The first part of the series is a standard logarithmic series shoes sum is $\frac {-1}{2} (\log \frac 32 +\log \frac 12)$, but I don’t not know how to deal with the second part, which I also believe is a logarithmic expansion

Comment: Are these separate series? I don't see the pattern.

Comment: What is the series for $\frac1{2x}(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x))$?

Comment: @DerekLuna I separated them

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I tried that, but you need the same number as the exponent and the denominator

Comment: $S'=1+\frac13\frac1{2^2}+\frac15\frac1{2^4}...$ and $\frac1{2x}(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x))=1+x^2/3+x^4/5...$. Keep $x=1/2$. Do they not match?

Comment: I can't understand what's the relation between the series that **seems** to be given in the question's title, and the one that seems to be given in the body of the question...Pretty confusing. Is the series in the body of the question a separated form of the one in the title?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. What is the series for $\frac1{2x}(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x))$?

> $$S'=1+\frac13\cdot\frac1{2^2}+\frac15\cdot\frac1{2^4}...$$and$$\frac1{2x}(\log(1+x)-\log(1-x))=1+x^2/3+x^4/5...$$Now keep $x=1/2$.

Comment: I didn’t think about dividing by $x$. So it will be $\log 2\sqrt 3$. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The **series given in your title** is the following with $x=1/4$:
$$\begin{align}
S(x)&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)x^k
=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{2k+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}+\frac{1}{z}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\\
&=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{2}+\frac{-\log(1-z)+\log(1+z)}{2z}
\end{align}$$
where $z=\sqrt{x}$.
Finally, we get
$$S(1/4)=\frac{\log(3)}{2}+\log(2).$$

Comment: @Aditya This is the series given in your title!